# how to tune OS level file descriptors for maximum boost ASIO performance

Tags: c++, linux, performance, boost-asio, file-descriptor

I'm building a websocket++ server, and I want to make sure I'm getting every last drop of performance out of it.

zaphoyd, the author, has said that OS level file descriptors must be properly tuned to have 10,000+ client connections.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/15464445/1382306

How can this be done for linux/ubuntu?

Comment: It may be worth reading the [C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html).

Comment: @TannerSansbury Seconding this, while a bit on the old side, Kegel's site is great introduction to the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Getting every last drop of performance" is not something you can do in the abstract. It varies too much based on your application and environment. To get a useful answer set up a stress/load testing harness, run a profiler, and see where things break or where the bottlenecks are. Until you do this and have some real world scenarios and numbers any effort spent on "performance tuning" will likely be wasted.

Specifically with respect to the question of tuning Linux servers to allow large numbers of concurrent connections.. Each connection requires a file descriptor. By default on Linux each process is limited to 1024 FDs. To even have >~1024 connections at once you will need that limit bumped up. This doesn't affect performance per say, but is required to even start thinking about performance tuning at high concurrency levels.

for more information see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36841/why-is-number-of-open-files-limited-in-linux and
https://serverfault.com/questions/190435/how-to-increase-open-files-limit-for-process-from-1024-to-10240